# Windows Phone 8: Media file access

Tags: c#, c++, file-io, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8

Are there means to access audio and video files from the default audio/video folders in Windows Phone 8? I already checked this document but all methods (for instance KnownFolders.MusicLibrary) are not implemented on the WP8: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx

I need access to the raw file data. It would also be fine to access the data from a Windows Phone Runtime or from pure C++ if it's not possible from C#.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

KnownFolders doesn't work on WP8 for 3rd party apps.

In terms of access on WP8 here's what's available:

- **Contacts**: Read access available since WP7.5, write-access available via WP8 ContactStore.
- **Appointments**: Read-access available since WP7.5. In WP8 you can add individual appointments after user confirmation via the SaveAppointmentTask.
- **Photos**: Read access to all folders available since WP7. Write-access to Camera Roll and Saved Pictures available since WP7.5.
- **Audio**: Developers can iterate over the music library and even play it via the native player since WP7. Starting WP8 developers can add songs to the music library using MediaLibraryExtensions.SaveSong().
- **Video**: Read-write isn't available. There are security and storage issue with transporting files that big.
- **uSD Card**: Starting WP8 apps can register for specific file extensions and read those from the micro-SD card.
- **Documents**: No read-write access. But starting WP8 developers can open up docx/xlsx/etc files using Launcher.LaunchFileAsync and it will open up a read-only copy in Office. Users can then choose to save that copy in the Office Hub.

I've made this post a wiki so if there are any additional areas, feel free to edit and add those bullet points.

Comment: It's a real pitty that the WP8 file access system model is so strict, even not allowing read (write) acccess to Video or Music folders.

Comment: What about the favorites folder, for photos?  The folder shows up in the MediaLibrary object, but is always empty.  Is there any way to get those files from code?

Answer (score 6):

With the introduction of Windows Phone 8.1 you can now access KnownFolders. Here is a screenshot of me saving to the video folder (Xbox Video app)
[image: KnownFolders access]

Comment: mh intersting, but do you know if we can or not delete file from the device ? Since the app ? Thanks so much for this answer

Answer (score 0):

Consider upgrading your project to Windows Phone 8.1 which has access to

Pictures Library, Music Library, Video Library

Check this out

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn639127.aspx