# create setting page for windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, alarm

I am new to developing I am developing simple alarm based application I want to create one setting page. I want to change alarm tone from setting how can I did that please help me. how can I show all songs from music library and set as alarm tone.

Answer (score 1):

No, you **cannot** pick a song from the music library and use it for the alarm tone. The [alarm API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.scheduler.alarm) doesn't support this.

Take a look at the `Sound` property is the `Alarm` API.

```
public Uri Sound { get; set; }
```

You can either embed music files in your app and reference them using a `Uri` or let the app download songs from the Internet and then store them in the `IsolatedStorage`, just to get the `Uri`.

Comment: ok then how can i show all audio files which are stored in my application assets folder and i want to show all files to user and select anyone form them as a alarm tone from setting page?? can you give me any source code for that setting page??

Comment: Check out this link. And search for the line `alarm.Sound = new Uri("/Ringtones/Ring01.wma", UriKind.Relative);` It's pretty clear what you need to do in regards to alarm tones.

Answer (score 0):

alarm -
you need to select Music Library contract in Appmanifest>Capabilities which will allow you to get all music file's in the User's music library. But the user can always decline your app the permission to use the Music Library.

```
    var folder = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;
    var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to retrieve the songs from the `Media Library`:

```
using(MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary())
{
foreach(var song in library.Songs)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Name: " + song.Name);
    Debug.WriteLine("Artist: " + song.Artist.Name);
    Debug.WriteLine("Album: " + song.Album.Name);
}
}
```

For more you could refer this: [Windows phone 8 get files in folder Music or Documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695930/)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Steps on how to create a settings page for Windows Phone application is available in MSDN: ["How to create a settings page for Windows Phone 8"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769510(v=vs.105).aspx)

Other articles that might be interesting for your application:

[How to Create a WP7 Alarm Application?](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2011/06/windows-phone-7-mango-tutorial-16-how.html)

[Your Last About Dialog - easy way to add about page into the app](https://ylad.codeplex.com/).