# So there is no way to access videos on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I need to access videos on camera roll and also on Music+Video. but it seems there is no way at all.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769558%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) in the documentation says we can use:

```
MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
```

But it only can access musics.

Can we say I should forget this thing for ever in WP8?

Comment: Interact means? Videos generally are not interactive :)

Comment: sorry :) non-native speakers problems.. I have edited it

Comment: I also want to upload the video on youtube using my app, can't i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to access videos in Media Library. 
You have read-write access only to audio and photos.
See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13473349/1029518

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple answers in the following thread which points out it is now feasible to read the video files via KnownFolders if you upgrade to Windows Phone 8.1: [Windows Phone 8: Media file access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467701/windows-phone-8-media-file-access)

Here is an alternative option for accessing the videos (also in Windows Phone 8.1):

```
        FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker();
        picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
        picker.PickSingleFileAndContinue();
```

Once you have the file you should be able to play it back.