# Getting captured video from Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, video-capture

While Microsoft appears to have a robust video capture API for Windows Phone 8, it appears that any videos captured must be stored in the application's local storage, which is not accessible from the File Explorer when the WinPhone 8 device is connected to a Windows 8 PC.

Also, the app cannot store the videos anywhere the user could easily copy them from the phone.  It is limited to its own isolated file system.  This stackOverflow posting explains how the Win8 phone is locked down:

[Windows Phone 8: Media file access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467701/windows-phone-8-media-file-access/13473349#13473349)

So, I can capture and store a video, but how do I get it off the phone to somewhere a user can manipulate it?

Comment: Use skydrive. That seems to be the way that most apps get around these issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you want those captured video off your phone then you can email/share it using ShareMediaTask & then can get that video out off the phone.
May be its not worth your requirement but if the purpose is to get it out off phone then it will help.