# Get music's date when it was added to windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to get date when some .mp3 file was added on device? I want it to use for example to show songs that was recently added or sort music by date.

Comment: You mean added to IsolatedStorage?

Comment: @Romasz No, I need to get date when music was added to device memory and sd-card memory.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you won't be able to do that.
You can do [limited operations with Music Hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467701/windows-phone-8-media-file-access), even if you manage to get a song from MediaLibrary there is [no such public property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.song_members.aspx) like creation date (or similar).
As for the SD card - you don't have direct access to music files on SD - these are [reserved file associations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207065(v=vs.105).aspx) - you won't see that files when you list SD card in your app. Also files on sd have [date modified](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.storage.externalstoragefile(v=vs.105).aspx) but not 'created'.
Maybe it will change in the future, but for now it's like this.