# Picking video from phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am trying to pick video from the phone and since openFilePicker doesn't work I am stacked. Are the  native apps the only solution or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

Read-Write operations are not available for Video files in windows phone 8 applications. Here this link will let you know more; [Windows Phone 8 Media File Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467701/windows-phone-8-media-file-access)

Comment: Is it impossible even with the native c++?

Comment: No Microsoft has not provided any api's to make read or write operations on media elements in windows phone 8.