# Windows Phone 8.0 - Access phone's local storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, local-storage, filepicker

Is there any API that enables me to access the phone's local storage files and folders ? I want to implement a file picker that displays the folders and files hierarchy just like they are in folder explorer:

[image: windows phone local storage]

Microsoft has released a free app called "`Files`" that does exactly what I want and more. Is it a special case or its possible for any developer?

Note: Im programming a `WP8.0` app and not `WP8.1.` [File Picker sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-picker-sample-9f294cba) won't work for me! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API in WP8 to list all the files in storage. In WP8 you can only access Audio and image files.

For more details refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13473349/2256349).