# Download and save .pdf file in Documents/Download Folder - WP8 Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, pdf, windows-phone-8

Direct to the point: I want to download and save a .pdf file so that the user can see it later in the Media Library.

I'm looking for a way to achieve this in Windows Phone 8 Silverlight.

Here is the code I'm using right now:

```
private void DownloadPDF(string url)
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        client.OpenReadCompleted += client_OpenReadCompleted;

        this.FileName = Path.GetFileName(url);

        client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(url));
    }

    async void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Save file:

        var buffer = new byte[e.Result.Length];
        await e.Result.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        using (var storageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (var stream = storageFile.OpenFile(this.FileName, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
        }

        // Open file:
        var local = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        var pdffile = await local.GetFileAsync(this.FileName);
        Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(pdffile);

        var progressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator()
        {
            IsVisible = false
        };

        SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator(this, progressIndicator);
    }
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is the question actually

Comment: I'd like to save files in a way users can see them in Media Library folders. I'm currently using IsolatedStorage and I can't see files outside the app  @Eldho

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467701/windows-phone-8-media-file-access/13473349#13473349

Comment: Mhm... So I guess it's just not posible. Thank you very much! @Eldho